# Return from a C++0x lambda caller directly

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, return-type

I've just rewritten the following C89 code, that returns from the current function:

```
// make sure the inode isn't open
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN(g_cpfs->htab); ++i)
    {
        struct Handle const *const handle = &g_cpfs->htab[i];
        if (handle_valid(handle))
        {
            if (handle->ino == (*inode)->ino)
            {
                log_info("Inode "INO_FMT" is still open, delaying removal.",
                        (*inode)->ino);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this C++0x STL/lambda hybrid:

```
std::for_each(g_cpfs->htab.begin(), g_cpfs->htab.end(), [inode](Handle const &handle) {
    if (handle.valid()) {
        if (handle.ino == inode->ino) {
            log_info("Inode "INO_FMT" is still open, delaying removal.", inode->ino);
            return true;
        }
    }});
```

Which generates:

> 1>e:\src\cpfs4\libcpfs\inode.cc(128): error C3499: a lambda that has been specified to have a void return type cannot return a value

I hadn't considered that the return in the lambda, doesn't actually return from the caller (having never seen a scoped function in C/C++ before now). **How do I `return true` from the caller where the original function would have done so?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't; std::for_each isn't structured to handle an early return.  You could throw an exception...

Or don't use a lambda:

```
for (auto const &handle : g_cpfs->htab) {
  // code that was in lambda body
}
```

Comment: Note "range-based for loops" (as the 0x draft calls them) are "foreach loops", which is what you were trying to get from std::for_each.

Comment: The foreach syntax is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: yeah, I removed that comment again. I assumed he meant `for_each` syntax. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [std::find_if()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) instead of `std::for_each()`:

```
if (std::find_if(g_cpfs->htab.begin(), g_cpfs->htab.end(),
        [inode](Handle const &handle) {
            if (handle.valid() && handle.ino == inode->ino) {
                log_info("Inode "INO_FMT" is still open, delaying removal.",
                    inode->ino);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }) != g_cpfs->htab.end()) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: While find_if does work at fixing the loop impedance mismatch, using it with if and the return values like that feels wrong.

Comment: @Roger, yup, I also had to use pretty weird indentation to make it readable. It works, though, so I don't know if that's really an issue...

Comment: It does feel weird, but this is the best way to do it, given that MSVC2010 doesn't seem to support range-based for?

Comment: @Matt, or you could wait for VC++ 2011 ;)

Comment: @Matt: BOOST_FOREACH? (You can also copy the code for MSVC, Boost is *very* liberally licensed.) "Regular" begin/end for loop?